# How do I make an image carousel with JavaScript that changes photos at the exact same time in sync with CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, css-animations

I'm trying to make an image carousel that shows three photos that fade-out and fade-in when they change, but I can't figure out how to make all three images change at once while in sync with the fade-out fade-in animation.

what I thought I would do was have a div containing 3 divs with images. then through js I make an array of all the images I want to use then randomly select a photo. But then the photo can't show up twice in one slide, so I add a condition and another array to check if the photo was already used. Then I swap the images after 5 seconds with setInterval, adding a CSS animation to the main container div.

I'm also open to another way of displaying photos in a randomized order instead of this one.

Full code: https://srcshare.io/?id=60dd3c0ad56829604d39814b

```
...
               
    let waitFor = 5000;
    let imgs = document.getElementById("wrapper");

    function fadeInOut() {
                        let animation = "fade " + waitFor + "ms linear infinite";
        imgs.style.animation = animation;
    }
    function fadeStop() {

        imgs.style.animation = "";
    }

    let firstImg = document.getElementById('image1');
    let secondImg = document.getElementById('image2');
    let thirdImg = document.getElementById('image3');

    setInterval(function () {

        fadeStop();


        let imgSlots = ["", "", ""];
        let alreadyPicked = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            let slotFull = false;

            while (!slotFull) {


                let sponsor = Math.floor(Math.random() * sponsorList.length);
                if (!alreadyPicked.includes(sponsorList[sponsor])) {

                    imgSlots[i] = sponsorList[sponsor][1];
                    alreadyPicked.push(sponsorList[sponsor]);
                    slotFull = true;
                }

            }

        }
        
            fadeInOut();
            firstImg.src = imgSlots[0];
            secondImg.src = imgSlots[1];
            thirdImg.src = imgSlots[2];

    }, waitFor);



});

</script>
```

```
<style>
  /*IMAGE CORNER CURVATURE*/
  img{
    border-radius: 0px;
   
  }
  
/*for sponsorship images*/
.inline{
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: clamp(100px,16vw,350px) !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  
}
  .wrapper{
    opacity: 0;
  }


@keyframes fade {
  0%,100%{opacity:0}
  15%,85%{ opacity: 1 }

}
</style>
```